# Duplicate content - Redirecting mirror sites

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, duplicate-content

A domain has 12 mirror sites and all of them are indexed. As a matter of fact one of the mirror domains (44 Moz domain authority) is competing with the primary domain (62 Moz domain authority) on page 1 of SERP for a number of keywords. All mirrored sites were done via domain registrar's DNS dashboard so there is no server to do the 301s.

Is setting up each mirrored domain on new hosting server and doing one to one 301 redirects to the main domain the best bet?

Comment: They do not have to be on the same server (though that is likely wise), however, doing a 301 redirect seems wise to me. As well, when you say mirror sites, I assume a dozen domains (not sub-domains) all with the exact same content. If this is the case, it is probably also wise just to drop the unneeded domains. Pick one and be done. My two centavos. That and a donkey will get you a cup of coffee! Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc Yup all domain mirror the content of the main domain via one of those stupid features that Network Solutions has as part of their DNS settings. The goal is to do 301 on all mirror sites and point everything to the main domain.

Comment: I am not sure why anyone pays NetSol for anything these days. They were trying recruit Cricket Liu (Author of DNS and Bind) back in the day. When they could not get Cricket, they tried to recruit me. The decision was an easy one. Run away! I had contacts high up that allowed me to make immediate changes to any registration, but that was as far as I wanted to get involved. When GoDaddy came about, as a web host, I transferred almost all of the domains immediately and never looked back.

Comment: @closetnoc So I setup 1 to 1 redirects and added all sites to Search Console. Is it worth telling G that those mirror sites moved to the primary domain? Most have Moz DA under 5 and two are in the mid 40s.

Comment: I am not sure about telling G anything in Search Console. I would investigate using a canonical tag on any duplicate pages. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en look for the header *Indicate the preferred URL with the rel="canonical" link element* for an example. You always want to point to the primary/original/want to rank page. That should be enough. G has a way of figuring things out okay. It just may take time. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc I had to do 301's instead of canonical because client's CMS vendor never heard of it and is unwilling to make the change.

Comment: I gave up on working with the vendor. Will do 301s today and see how it goes.

Comment: Please update on how it went! Battling with a similar problem at the moment, except it's subdomains mirroring the content from the main domain. Did you have access to analytics for each of the mirror domains? I'd also check the backlinks for each domain (currently live and historic backlinks) and attempt to do some link clean-up - contacting webmasters and kindly asking to update the URL to go to the preferred domain. Agree with @closetnoc that you could consider just dropping one or a small batch and observe what happens, without going the 301 route.

Comment: @Jurga I did have access to the other sites. Unfortunately, since the sites were all mirrored, the GA code was the same. I did do the 301s and told G that the mirrored sites have moved by submitting the change of address. I will post an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is soley about SERP ranking and these sites are direct mirrors of your primary site (ie: no change to the content on any of the mirrors) then the other option would be to add a `rel='canonical'` meta tag to each page ti identify the primary domain as the canonical page. This was specifically done to allow duplicated content such as from mirrors to work properly with SERP ranking. By doing this you will not affect the root benefit of a mirror site (where the content is accessible under multiple domains, if this is in fact required) but you will retain the primary site as the authoratative source for the mirrored sites as well and will maintain the primary site as a high level in SERP ranking.